# Matlab: boxplot at uneven spacing

Tags: matlab, boxplot

Consider the following example for plotting boxplot in Matlab, which I have taken from [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html#mw_a44ef1f1-e8e4-460d-93d1-b2b0af2ab126).

```
rng('default')  % For reproducibility
x1 = rand(5,1);
x2 = rand(10,1);
x3 = rand(15,1);
x = [x1; x2; x3];
g1 = repmat({'First'},5,1);
g2 = repmat({'Second'},10,1);
g3 = repmat({'Third'},15,1);
g = [g1; g2; g3];
% Create the box plots.
boxplot(x,g)
```

The above will boxplot at equal intervals, for which I can change the xticks. What I want is to boxplot at uneven abscissa values, lets say at abscissa = [1.1, 2.5, 4.6]

Thanks

Comment: Can't you always just update the `'XTickLabels'`? `abscissa = [1.1, 2.5, 4.6];`
Then after the plot, `set(gca,'XTickLabels',abscissa)` ?  This worked for me but I might not fully understand what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks @SecretAgentMan for the comment and sorry if I have not made my question clear, but I got what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I got it, that was simple

```
abscissa = [1.1, 2.5, 4.6]
boxplot(x, g, 'positions', abscissa , 'labels', abscissa )
```